# Unable to build Android project from the command line

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am trying to build an Android project from the command line by following the documentation at https://developer.android.com/build/building-cmdline

I am trying to build it in a CentOS machine. I have installed the Android SDK and JDK 21.
However, on running any gradle task by the command `./gradlew task-name`, I am getting the following error:

```
> Task :tasks FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':tasks'.
> Could not create task ':app:compileBlackBox32DebugAndroidTestKotlin'.
   > Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method AbstractKotlinCompile.execute() because interface org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid parameter to an action method.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BUILD FAILED in 896ms
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

I have searched the internet, but found nothing that can help me solve the issue. I have also tried changing the JDK version to 17, but still the same error was shown.
What can be the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: AFIK JDK 21 is not yet a suitable JDK that van be used for Android development. Depending on the gradle and Android tools used you need JDK 17 or JDK 11.

Comment: As I said in the question, I have also tried it with JDK 17.

Comment: Your error shows `incompatible with Gradle 9.0` but your comment below indicates 8.5. Just as a baseline are you able to run/build with gradle a 'hello world' Android app on your CentOS machine.

Comment: @MorrisonChang That is a warning shown to indicate that some deprecated features are being used in the current project, but they will be removed in the next release of gradle. I will try to build a sample app and check if the error still exists.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me a mismatch between ->

**gradle build version**
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:x.x.x'

**Android gradle plugin ...**
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-x.x-bin.zip

By fix these versions or correcting these version should fix the build error...

**note :**

**1. you can find both of these versions in android studio where its building fine.**

**2. compileOptions & kotlinOptions must be Java 11 or JDK 17.(Below 11 is not accepted)**

Comment: I have also tried it with JDK 17. My Gradle version is 8.5, and AGP version is 8.2.2. According to https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin, they should be compatible.

Comment: Try "gradlew build_variant --stacktrace"
stacktrace -> gives you more insights on error